# Stacked ggplot2 geom_area reruns an empty graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-area

I am trying to us geom_area to produce a stacked area graph but it producing an entry graph. Here is an example

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

x = expand.grid(name = c("D01", "D02", "D03", "D04"), component = c("F", "W", "M", "V"))
value = runif( min = 20, max = 150, nrow(x))

data2 = cbind(x, value) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(name)

ggplot2::ggplot(data = data2, aes(x = name, fill = factor(component))) + 
                  ggplot2::geom_area(aes(y = value), position = 'stack')
```

I read the questions [Why is my stacked area graph in ggplot2 empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357180/why-is-my-stacked-area-graph-in-ggplot2-empty/43382776)  and [Why is my stacked area graph in ggplot2 empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357180/why-is-my-stacked-area-graph-in-ggplot2-empty)  but the solutions posted there they did not resolve my problem. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: @akrun sorry I edited the question.

Comment: i get an error `Error in f(...) : Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon`

Comment: That should have been coming from group = 1, I deleted that.

Comment: the `name` is `factor` column.  According to `?geom_area `An area plot is the continuous analogue of a stacked bar chart (see geom_bar()), and can be used to show how composition of the whole varies over the range of x.`

Comment: so how can I produce a stacked area plot when my x variable is a character or a factor?

Comment: You can convert the factor to numeric with `as.numeric/as.integer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we convert the 'x' `factor` to `integer`, it should work

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data2 %>% 
     mutate(name = as.integer(name)) %>%
     ggplot(aes(x = name, fill = component)) +
         geom_area(aes(y = value), position = 'stack')+
         scale_x_continuous(labels = levels(data2$name))
```

[image]